# Multiple VLANs in the same subnet

Tags: subnet, esxi

Is it possible to have multiple VLANs in the same subnet, with the same gateway address (TMG).
note that I don't want them to connect to each other, so ARP/inter-vlan routing (within the subnet) is not required.

I want to avoid having many Subnets (and vNIC's in TMG) just to isolate sets of a few hosts.

```
IP: 10.0.0.1         (TMG server)       VLAN:1 ~ 3

IP: 10.0.0.11 ~ 20   (Hosts group 1)    VLAN:1

IP: 10.0.0.21 ~ 30   (Hosts group 2)    VLAN:2

IP: 10.0.0.31 ~ 40   (Hosts group 3)    VLAN:3
```

the gateway is running in a VM within ESXi 5, I can pass the VLans to the VM using VGT or VLan Range but I don't know how the OS should handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that's possible to have multiple VLANs in the same subnet.
But it's impossible to have one TMG for multiple VLANs, from the guest OS side, each switch VLAN interface can bind only one primary address. Either untag or tagged traffic can pass VLAN 1-3 range.